# Logically merging 4 columns of the same information

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm querying 3 different databases (4 total fields) for their "username" field given a particular machine name in our environment: SCCM, McAfee EPO, and ActiveDirectory.

The four columns are SCCM_TOP, SCCM_LAST, EPO, AD

Some of the tuples I get look like:

```
JOE, JOE, ADMINISTRATOR, JOE

or
JOE, SARAH, JOE, JOE

or
NULL, NULL, JOE, JOE

or
NULL, NULL, JOE, SARAH
```

The last example of which is the most difficult to code against.

I'm writing a CASE statement to help merge the information in an additive way to give one 
final column of the "best guess". At the moment, I'm weighing the most valid username based on another column, which is "age of the record" from each database.

```
CASE 
 WHEN ePO_Age <= CT_AGE AND NOT ePO_UN IS NULL THEN ePO_UN 
 WHEN NOT (SCCM_AGE) IS NULL AND NOT (SCCM_LAST_UN) IS NULL THEN SCCM_LAST_UN
 WHEN NOT (SCCM_AGE) IS NULL AND NOT (SCCM_TOP_UN) IS NULL THEN SCCM_TOP_UN 
 WHEN NOT (AD_UN) IS NULL THEN AD_UN 
 ELSE NULL 
 END                  AS BestName,
```

But there has to be a better way to combine these records into one. My next step is to weigh the "average age" and then pick the username from there, discarding "Administrator".

Any thoughts or tricks?

Answer (score 1):

You could benefit a little from the COALESCE function to get the first NON-NULL value and do something like:

```
COALESCE(CASE WHEN ePO_Age<=CT_AGE THEN ePO_UN END,
         CASE WHEN SCCM_AGE IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(SCCM_LAST_UN, SCCM_TOP_UN) END,
         AD_UN) AS BestName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the most recent UserName that isn't null, try using `UNION` to combine the results from each table.

```
SELECT TOP 1 qry.UserName
FROM(
  SELECT UserName, CreateDate
  FROM UserNames_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT UserName, CreateDate
  FROM UserNames_2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT UserName, CreateDate
  FROM UserNames_3
 ) AS qry
WHERE qry.UserName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY qry.CreateDate DESC
```

Have a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73f3e/5/0)